# Can I use pytoch amp functions, GradScaler and autocast on the CPU?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am currently trying to debug my code and would like to run it on the CPU, but I am using `torch.cuda.amp.autocast()` and `torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()`, which are part of the Automatic Mixed Precision package that is from `cuda` and will be automatically on GPU.

Is there a way to use these functions on the CPU? If not, what alternative approaches can I use to achieve similar functionality on the CPU? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No they are specifically designed to work with CUDA-based GPUs. we can't say exact functionality but there are some like `torch.half()` or `torch.bfloat16()` which can convert the weights and gradients to lower precision types like float16 or bfloat16.